# [Excel]- How Can I use Countifs that must satisfy both criteria for it to count?

Tags: excel, formula, countif

So I am using the below code

=COUNTIFS('Incident Register'!M2:M208,"Condition of the Workplace",'Incident Register'!C2:C208,Sheet1!J8)

First condition goes over the incident register and checks whether the primary cause is due to "Condition of the Workplace" and the second criteria checks whether the date is equal to the date on the other tab of the excelsheet.

So the problem I am facing is that when the countIf criteria 1 is satisfied it counts given that it has "Condition of the Workplace" but it also counts other incidents with the same date because it satisfied the second criteria while it did not satisfy the first criteria.

e.g
2023/01/01 - Condition of the workplace  This is correct and should count.
2023/01/01 - x                           This is incorrect because it does not have "Condition of the work place" but in countifts it seems to count due to the fact that it still satisfies the first criteria.

Can anyone please help me...

I tried usig AND but failed...

Comment: I find countifs() usually works fine, so may be somethjing with your data. Why not check by using match() for both criteria and AND() to find out how many meet both.

Comment: ur formula is missing somthing... it should be (in the format of ) `=COUNTIFS(range1,criteria1,range2,criteria2)`  look like urs are missing the `criteria2` | ref https://exceljet.net/functions/countifs-function